# Does the high frequency of a dummy variable make it seem it is significant?

Tags: regression, anova, p-value, categorical-encoding

Looking at IMDb scores (dependent) and movie genres (independent), and coding genres to binary dummy variables (action yes=1, no action=0, drama yes=1, no drama=0, etc.). Dramas are highly popular movies with more movies than others listing drama as a genre. Drama p-value is significant with linear regression and ANOVA.

Would it be possible for it to seem like dramas are more likely to have high scores just because dramas are such a popular genre and simply occur more often?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What does this regression predict?

Comment: Hi! It predicts each movie genre’s relationship with IMDb score (hope that makes sense. I’m a newbie).

Comment: What's the size of your dataset? How many drama ratings do you have? The sample size determines how accurately you estimate the average drama rating (the width of its confidence interval), not whether the average drama rating is low or high.

Comment: Hi! This dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/victorsoeiro/netflix-tv-shows-and-movies. It is quite large